# Pulling alt info from wordpress media library + ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, alt

So what i'm trying to do it pull the image alt info from the media library in Wordpress. The site needs to be heavily 508 so i'm pulling it in for every image. Trying to get this working initially and am having some issues. In this instance i'm getting the image from my "options" page that I set up with ACF. Here is the code i'm using.

```
<?php  $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('footer_logo', 'option'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>"></a>
```

I think that fact that the image is coming from ACF it's not pulling it but i'm not to sure so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually changed up the code a little to achieve the same gaol

```
        <?php
            $image = get_field('a1_image');
            $thumb = $image['sizes'][ 'home-announcement' ];
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"/>
```

With the ACF option set to image array.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an ACF image field, you could just do the following:

```
<?php $image = get_field('footer_logo'); ?>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"></a>
```

[See ACF Image documentation.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

Comment: since pulling from a options page it needs to use the "the_field('footer_logo', 'option'); " code but this is not pulling up anything, In the front end i get a path to where my image is with no front part /wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logo-footer.png

Comment: The second parameter of [`the_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) should be a post ID, it can't be a string.